# Работа с формой

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, форма

Здравствуйте, мне нужно из другой функции работать с формой другого класса, делаю я это так:

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1 form = new Form1();
            класс.функция(form);
        }
```

функция в классе выглядит так:

```
public static void функция(Form form)
    {
        form = new Form();
        //Работа с формой
    }
```

но зачем-то функция создает новую форму, и работает с ней. Как работать с переданной формой?

Comment: простите, вы в своем уме? вы пишете 

    form = new Form();

и потом еще удивляетесь: "но зачем-то функция создает новую форму"

Comment: Я делаю переносимую библиотеку, откуда я знаю как называется форма? А так я тупанул немного.

Comment: >класс.функция(form);

а это уже 1С головного мозга

Comment: <<Я не использую кириллицу в коде, это образно.

Comment: ваш код настолько ужасен, что вы стесняетесь его показать?

Comment: Нет, вот он:
public static void Draw(int[] vector, System.Drawing.Color hehe) {
       Form1 form = new Form1();
       System.Drawing.SolidBrush Brush = 
       new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(hehe);
       System.Drawing.Graphics formGraphics = this.CreateGraphics();
       formGraphics.FillRectangle(Brush, new              System.Drawing.Rectangle(vector[0],vector[1],vector[2],vector[3]));
       brush1.Dispose();
       formGraphics.Dispose();
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы же сами новую форму и создаете, причем дважды. Сначала в `button1_Click`:

```
Form1 form = new Form1();
```

а затем в вашем методе:

```
form = new Form();
```

Выкиньте это из своего кода и передавайте из `button1_Click` **`this`**.

P.S.: Даже не думайте о том, чтобы использовать кириллицу в коде. И еще: то, что вы назвали функцией, называется методом. В C# нет функций, есть только методы.

Comment: Я и не использовал ее в коде :) Это образно